# TypeError: window[("check" + key)] is not a function

Tags: javascript, firefox

In firefox 61.0.2 x64 with JQuery 3.3.1 I'm getting the following console error;

> TypeError: window[("check" + key)] is not a function

But the actual function is working correctly and only throws this error in FF. But it has the effect of breaking the script and wont run any code below that line in its current state.

```
/* Save Check Box State for session */
var checkboxValues = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('checkboxValues')) || {},
    $checkboxes = $("#checkbox-container :checkbox");

    $checkboxes.on("change", function(){
    $checkboxes.each(function(){
        checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
        });
        sessionStorage.setItem("checkboxValues", JSON.stringify(checkboxValues));
    });

$.each(checkboxValues, function(key, value) {
    $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
    if (value === true )
    {
        window['check'+key]();
    }
});
```

`check+key` returns something like `checkautoRefresh()` The idea is on a page re-load any checked boxes are still checked and the function (re)called.

The offending functions:

```
function checkautoRefresh() {
    if ($("#autoRefresh").is(":checked")) {
        reloader=setTimeout("window.location.reload();", 30000);
    }
}

function autoRefresh(cb) {
    if (cb.checked) {
        reloader=setTimeout("window.location.reload();", 30000);
    } else {
        clearTimeout(reloader);
    }
}
```

I've made a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ctwjsh39/1/) with the full Java Script and a html checkbox. If you set the check box, open the console and reload the page you should get the error, but the refresh function will work as expected. In IE there is no error and all the rest of the script below this section runs, and I don't remember this error in previous versions of FF (Though I'm not immediately able to go back through the versions & check.)

I need to find a fix, or better way to do what I'm doing where the check box states are saved then recalled on reload and the function called again to apply any filters/settings etc. This code is a working extract from a bigger page which pulls data from a database for user display.

My javascript file is loaded in the `<head>` section of my `php` code.

Comment: Your fiddle is set to run onload so the methods in the fiddle are not global. Your code is basically `window.onload = function() { function foo(){} }`. Click the gear icon and make it run at the end of the body.

Comment: AH, JSFiddle is just clicking on the javascript/jquery line

Comment: @epascarello Weird - you are correct the error is gone. I presume something change in FF? How do I translate this fix to my site/code?

Comment: Has nothing to do with FF.... has to do witht he fact the variable was not global. No clue why it would happen on your site unless you are doing something similar.

Comment: @epascarello Even more weird then as my code didn't change since I wrote it. And if you try the same page in IE there is no error. I've done hardly anything with java till now so bare with me. It looks like any option beside under head or body will generate the error

Comment: In your real code, are the functions inside `$(document).ready()`? That would also take them out of the global scope. Instead of using global functions, it would be better to put them into an object whose keys are the checkbox values.

Comment: Yes! The entire section dealing with the check boxes is inside `$(document).ready(function() {`

Comment: well there you go.... you make them not in global scope if you defined the functions inside document.ready

Comment: If i move the entire section to the bottom of the javascript file (but still inside the doc.ready function the error goes. I don't understand but unless anyone else has something they want to write up as an answer I'll do it myself tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, moving;

```
$.each(checkboxValues, function(key, value) {
    $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
    if (value === true )
    {
        window['check'+key]();
    }
```

to the bottom of my loaded file appears to have resolved the issue. The fiddle still throws the same error if the code is called either on `.load` or `.ready` and I have no clue why as it was working code. I was also able to have 2 firefox consoles open where one would throw the error and the other would not all from the same url...